# How to take multipartFile as input?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, dropwizard

I am trying to create an image upload resource in java.
My functions looks like this:

```
Response fun(@FormDataParam("json") Employee emp, 
             @FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file){

}
```

If I give file input using postman, the value of file turns out to be null.
If I take `InputStream` as param in place of `MultipartFile` it works as expected.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: _"Am I missing something here?"_ - Yes; MultipartFile is for Spring MVC. These two frameworks are in no way compatible.

Comment: you can try following answer you will get the solutions

Comment: Why is this question tagged `dropwizard`? Do you want to use Dropwizard or Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Request Class:

```
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    public class UserDataForm {

        private String name;
        private List<MultipartFile> file;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public List<MultipartFile> getFile() {
            return file;
        }
        public void setFile(List<MultipartFile> file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserDataForm [name=" + name + ", file=" + file + "]";
        }
}
```

Second Config:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    //resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(10000); //Define your max or min file size
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

Controller layer:

```
    /*you can also remove @ModelAttribute that works same*/
        @RequestMapping(value = "userInfoTest" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseJson getInfo(@ModelAttribute UserDataForm user) {
            response.setResponse("Class Info" + user);
            return response;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and helpful explanation.